# Gatekeeper not showing kube-system pods as violations

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-web-services, helm, kubernetes-helm, eks

I am following this gatekeeper [guide](https://open-policy-agent.github.io/gatekeeper-library/website/validation/containerlimits/) and it gives violation if a pod doesn’t have limits but I am unable to see pods from kube-system namespace as violations.

I am testing this on AWS EKS.
I haven’t set any config to exempt kube-system in my constraints or in controller manager.

There is no config resource as well